MAUI workload & TargetFrameworks
I don't really know how to title this. I just started using MAUI and I have a few questions about it.

The first step to use MAUI is to run dotnet workload install or dotnet workload update. After running this command, I run dotnet workload list and I get this output:




Installed Workload Id
Manifest Version
Installation Source




ios
17.2.8053/8.0.100
SDK 8.0.200, VS 17.9.34728.123


maui
8.0.21/8.0.100
SDK 8.0.200


maui-windows
8.0.21/8.0.100
VS 17.9.34728.123


android
34.0.95/8.0.100
VS 17.9.34728.123


maccatalyst
17.2.8053/8.0.100
VS 17.9.34728.123



Coming from Xamarin, I imagine ios and android are the old Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android. The same concept for the other platforms when it comes to maui-windows and maccatalyst. But, what is maui workload? Has anything to do with NuGet packages Microsoft.Maui.Controls and Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatbility?

What does that Manifest Version mean? Is Android 34.0.95/8.0.100 meaning Android sdk 34.0.95 for .net 8.0.100?

By double clicking my project, I can see the following lines in it (I just left Android and iOS since I'm only deploying my application on those two):



What does that TargetFramework mean? How is it going to affect my Android manifest where I specify my Minimum Android Version is API 28 and the Target Android Version is API 34?

If you just started to use MAUI did you have a look at the documentation? Seems like you starting in the wrong end of things? .NET MAUI Tutorial - Build your first multi-platform app in C#

Of course I did. Nothing in my question is answered in the link you suggested.

@galex Is this the reason you are asking? : https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/20600

@H.A.H. no really specific issue behind the question. Just I would like to know more about the framework.


What does that Manifest Version mean?

Just as android 34.0.95/8.0.100, the 34.0.95 means the android version and 8.0.100 means the .net version.

What does that TargetFramework mean?

You can check this document about Configure multi-targeting. The folders for each target platform contain platform-specific code that starts the app on each platform, plus any additional platform code you add. At build time, the build system only includes the code from each folder when building for that specific platform. For example, when you build for Android the files in the Platforms > Android folder will be built into the app package, but the files in the other Platforms folders won't be.
.NET MAUI apps can also be multi-targeted based on your own filename and folder criteria. This enables you to structure your .NET MAUI app project so that you don't have to place your platform code into sub-folders of the Platforms folder.

What I was really wondering is how is that TargetFramework going to interact with the one I specify on my Android Manifest.
